# why does page go below container and footer div

Tags: html, css

I have created a web site that can be seen [here](http://chadi.rhpmgroup.com.au). Can anyone tell me why the text goes below the "container" div and "footer" div only on this page.

Any help would be appreciated. It is probably something simple I am missing, just can't work it out.

Comment: Probably because of your positioning of the container and the footer div. And also their sizes.

Comment: Close the main div container. Open a new one for footer alone.

Comment: can you expand a little please. container and footer divs are the same on other pages and no such issue.

Comment: Just check with the answers posted below by other members. That should fix, positioning problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix. Change this:

```
#about {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}
```

to this:

```
#about {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Perfectly <- adverb. Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

The #about has a `position: relative` and a `top:  100px`. Please remove the top 100px.

Before the #about you should put a clear div. Which means nothing more than a DIV.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

With the CSS

```
.clear { clear : both; }
```

Now you should be fine!